# How can I proxy a query string URL in Apache?

Tags: apache, proxy, urldecode

I'm trying to get an older Apache (2.2.17) to proxy:

http://foo.com/proxy/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fbar.com%2foo

to:

http://bar.com/foo

I have:

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/proxy/ %1? [P,L]

Unfortunately, this results in Apache trying to proxy the URL-encoded value (log output) :

(3) applying pattern '^/proxy/' to uri '/proxy/' 
(4) RewriteCond: input='url='http%3A%2F%2Fbar.com%2foo'' pattern='^url=(.*)$' => matched
(2) rewrite '/proxy/' -> ''http%3A%2F%2Fbar.com%2foo'?'
(3) split uri='http%3A%2F%2Fbar.com%2foo'? -> uri='http%3A%2F%2Fbar.com%2foo', args=
(2) forcing proxy-throughput with http://foo.com/'http%3A%2F%2Fbar.com%2foo'
(1) go-ahead with proxy request proxy:http://foo.com/'http%3A%2F%2Fbar.com%2foo' [OK]

So, it appears there are two problems.  One is that there are apostrophes in the result and the other is that the result is not URL decoded.  I assume the reason Apache is prepending the original protocol://host is that it doesn't see the result as an URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to vhost/server config (and it looks like you do), you can configure one of apache's built in rewrite maps to unescape for you:

```
RewriteMap unescape int:unescape
```

Then you can use the map in your rules:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/proxy/ ${unescape:%1}? [P,L]
```

Comment: This fixed the URL-decoding problem.  I'm now getting:

http://foo.com/'http://bar.com/foo'

How do I get rid of the apostrophes and get it to proxy the real URL?

Comment: @JayVachhani that shouldn't be there at all, this works for me in my apache install. Unless there's `'` around the url in the query string, I guess you can get rid of those optionally by changing the regex to: `^url='?(.*?)'?$`